# IBM App Connect Enterprise - Form Data in Rest Request Node

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

According to this IIB v10 link `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form data parameters are not supported for a Rest Request Node.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bi12026_.htm

Is this still the case for IIB 11? have they included support.

Is there another way to call a back-end API having form data parameters in the swagger file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got this done by a work around. Used an HTTP Request Node with the following ESQL in a compute node.

```
SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Content-Type" = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.QueryString.grant_type = 'client_credentials';
```

I know this is not an answer but this worked and retrieved my token.

Hope this helps to someone.

Comment: I see you put message as query string, but do you have any idea on how to send Form Data to this request, if we want to send data of grant_type, username and password etc. My requirement is send REST call with HTTPRequest with Form Data

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use BLOB domain in order to send a request with "x-www-form-urlencoded" header content-type in IIB.
Check below links for reference:

[Example1](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=23737)

[Example2](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=77698&sid=dddba8d501f9b04c68e0219bad9e9d6e)